# Plot histogram with classes in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram, seaborn

I'm trying to get a plot similar to the next one

[image]

but so far I have no idea how to get the classes. I have tried with matplotlib and seaborn but still don;t know how to incorporate the classes.

df.age.hist()

or

g = sns.pairplot(df, hue='class')

Actually what I want is the diagonal of the pairplot in seaborn

Comment: `if code == 0: print("No Help")`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bins = 10
data = np.random.randn(1000, 3)

colors = ['blue','green', 'red']
plt.hist(data, bins, histtype='bar', color=colors, stacked=True, fill=True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So what you want to do is called Stack Bar Chart (at least I call it). I think `Bokeh` has an intuitive way to visualize this Bar Chart. This principle can also be applied to Pandas plot and Seaborn also.

**Bokeh library**

Here, I show an example of simple dataframe with 2 labels `a` and `b`. You can tell that you want to stack on `v1` which in this case are classes for each label. In this case, we will have class `1`, `0`. And also value corresponding what we want to stack which is `v2` in this case.

The code snippet to show Bar chart is as follows

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.charts import Bar, output_file, show

df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 0, 1], 
                   ['a', 1, 2], 
                   ['b', 0, 2], 
                   ['b', 1, 3]], 
               columns=['name', 'v1', 'v2'])


bar = Bar(df, stack='v1', values='v2', label='name')
output_file("bar.html")
show(bar)
```

[image]

**Pandas library**

For Pandas, you can use `groupby` and `sum` instead. Here, we'll group by column `name` and `v1` then summing up the column `v2`. Later, we can stack use `plot` method in order to plot the Bar chart.

```
df_agg = df.groupby(['name', 'v1'])['v2'].sum().unstack()
df_agg.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```